# multiple selected items from listbox to select stored procedure in sql server using excel vba

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, listbox

I have a list box in `excel` that allows multiple selection, but i'm not sure how to pass the selected items to a single parameter for my sql server `stored procedure`. say i want to:

```
select * from where field in ('selected', 'items', 'from', 'list', 'box')
```

Any idea how to do this in excel with vba?

Comment: hello anyone have any idea?